# Как очистить от тегов спарсенную страницу?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Моя задача - собрать с сайта информацию и, при ее наличии, реализовать поисковый движок. Он затем будет искать информацию по сайту в соответствии с наибольшей релевантностью поисковой фразе. Сейчас передо мной задача, спарсив страницы, оставить в них только текст, без тегов. Причем код должен проверять всякий раз, не появилось ли на странице обновление, и если да, то спарсить и его.

Почему-то сейчас у меня страница с "мусором" в виде тегов, хотя ожидалось иное. Как поступить?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import walk
# модуль difflib содержит классы и функции для сравнения последовательностей (текстов)
import difflib
import re
import codecs  # модуль символьной перекодировки 

pages_list = []

# собираем список страниц, которые есть, для этого: проходим по raw_pages (папки на жестком диске со страницами):
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk('data/raw_pages'):
    if '.ipynb_checkpoints' in dirpath:
        continue
    
    dirpath = dirpath.replace('\\', '/') # для Windows
    for fn in filenames:
        if '.DS_Store' in fn:
            continue 
        fp = f'{dirpath}/{fn}'
        pages_list.append(fp)

def remove_script(file):
    """Функция облегчает жизнь difflib'у и удаляет скрипты, футеры и хедеры"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(file), 'html.parser')
    for s in soup.select('script'):
        # extract()удаляет тег или строку из дерева 
        # и возвращает тег или строку, которые были извлечены
        s.extract()
        
    for f in soup.select('footer'):
        f.extract()
    
    for f in soup.select('header'):
        f.extract()
        
    return str(soup).split('\n')

# Теперь из полученного списка берем 2 первых файла и очищаем их функцией remove_script:
fp_1 = 'data/raw_pages/zrg74.ru/obshhestvo/item/26920-chistovoe-vyrazhenie-v-zlatouste-oglasili-sroki-sdachi-10-jetazhki-dlja-vethoavarijshhikov.html'
fp_2 = 'data/raw_pages/zrg74.ru/obshhestvo/item/26924-verh-masterstva-v-zlatouste-blagoustrojstvo-jekotropy-urenga-zavershajut-rabotami-na-vysote.html'

with codecs.open(fp_1, 'r', 'utf_8_sig') as f:
    file1 = remove_script(f.readlines())
with codecs.open(fp_2, 'r', 'utf_8_sig') as f:
    file2 = remove_script(f.readlines())

def clean_diff(diff):
    """Функция очиcтки (пригодится позже)"""
    diff = re.sub('\<[^\<\>]+\>', ' ', diff)
    diff = re.sub('&nbsp;', ' ', diff)
    diff = re.sub('\xa0', ' ', diff)
    diff = re.sub('\s\s+', ' ', diff)
    diff = re.sub('^[\+\-] ', '', diff)
    
    return diff

# теперь сравним все страницы с «эталонной»: за нее возьмем первую же ссылку.
page_lines = []
for diff in difflib.ndiff(file1, file2): # с предобработкой данных
    if re.search('^\+ ', diff) is None:
        continue  
    diff = clean_diff(diff)
    if len(diff) == 0:
        continue
    page_lines.append(diff)
#     print(diff)
page_text = ' '.join(page_lines)
# print(page_text)
print(page_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать регулярные выражения из модуля `re`.

Пример кода:

```
import re

new_string = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', your_string)
```

Пример выполнения кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и сообщу, что получилось